# Fences in C++0x, guarantees just on atomics or memory in general

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-barriers, memory-model

The [C++0x draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) has a notion of fences which seems very distinct from a CPU/chip level notion of fences, or say what the linux kernel guys expect of [fences](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt). The question is whether the draft really implies an extremely restricted model, or the wording is just poor and it actually implies true fences.

For example, under *29.8 Fences* it states things like:

> A release fence A synchronizes with an
>   acquire fence B if there exist atomic
>   operations X and Y, both operating on
>   some atomic object M, such that A is
>   sequenced before X, X modiﬁes M, Y is
>   sequenced before B, and Y reads the
>   value written by X or a value written
>   by any side eﬀect in the hypothetical
>   release sequence X would head if it
>   were a release operation.

It uses these terms `atomic operations` and `atomic object`. There are such atomic operations and methods defined in the draft, but does it mean only those? A *release fence* sounds like a *store fence*. A *store fence* that doesn't guarantee the write of *all data* prior to the fence is nearly useless. Similar for a load (acquire) fence and full fence.

So, are the fences/barries in the C++0x proper fences and the wording just incredibly poor, or are they exremely restricted/useless as described?

---

In terms of C++, say I have this existing code (assuming fences are available as high level constructs right now -- instead of say using __sync_synchronize in GCC):

```
Thread A:
b = 9;
store_fence();
a = 5;

Thread B:
if( a == 5 )
{
  load_fence();
  c = b;
}
```

Assume a,b,c are of a size to have atomic copy on the platform. The above means that `c` will only ever be assigned `9`. Note we don't care when Thread B sees `a==5`, just that when it does it also sees `b==9`.

What is the code in C++0x that guarantees the same relationship?

---

**ANSWER**: If you read my chosen answer and all the comments you'll get the gist of the situation. C++0x appears to force you to use an atomic with fences whereas a normal hardware fence does not have this requirement. In many cases this can still be used to replace concurrent algorithms so long as `sizeof(atomic<T>) == sizeof(T)` and `atomic<T>.is_lock_free() == true`.

It is unfortunate however that `is_lock_free` is not a constexpr. That would allow it to be used in a `static_assert`. Having `atomic<T>` degenerate to using locks is generally a bad idea: atomic algorithms that use mutexes will have horrible contention problems compared to a mutex-designed algorithm.

Comment: Depleted uranium has been displaced as the material of choice for artillery shells.  Obsolete copies of the C++0x draft proved to be denser.

Comment: Though that one's only a month or so old.

Comment: Hans might know something we don't? The **real** proposal for C++11 will hopefully be released about next week.

Comment: why is that ff ligature in eﬀect rendered that way?

Comment: A mention of "atomic operation" in a specification, be it the standard or any other, can only reference those operations described as an "atomic operation" in that document, not to anything else that doesn't happen to be seen as half done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fences provide **ordering** on **all data**. However, in order to guarantee that the fence operation from one thread is visible to a second, you need to use atomic operations for the flag, otherwise you have a data race.

```
std::atomic<bool> ready(false);
int data=0;

void thread_1()
{
    data=42;
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    ready.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void thread_2()
{
    if(ready.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
    {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        std::cout<<"data="<<data<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

If `thread_2` reads `ready` to be `true`, then the fences ensure that `data` can safely be read, and the output will be `data=42`. If `ready` is read to be `false`, then you cannot guarantee that `thread_1` has issued the appropriate fence, so a fence in thread 2 would still not provide the necessary ordering guarantees --- if the `if` in `thread_2` was omitted, the access to `data` would be a data race and undefined behaviour, even with the fence.

Clarification: A `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)` is generally equivalent to a store fence, and will likely be implemented as such. However, a single fence on one processor does not guarantee any memory ordering: you need a corresponding fence on a second processor, **AND** you need to know that when the acquire fence was executed the effects of the release fence were visible to that second processor. It is obvious that if CPU A issues an acquire fence, and then 5 seconds later CPU B issues a release fence, then that release fence cannot synchronize with the acquire fence. Unless you have some means of checking whether or not the fence has been issued on the other CPU, the code on CPU A cannot tell whether it issued its fence before or after the fence on CPU B.

The requirement that you use an atomic operation to check whether or not the fence has been seen is a consequence of the data race rules: you cannot access a non-atomic variable from multiple threads without an ordering relationship, so you cannot use a non-atomic variable to check for an ordering relationship.

A stronger mechanism such as a mutex can of course be used, but that would render the separate fence pointless, as the mutex would provide the fence.

Relaxed atomic operations are likely just plain loads and stores on modern CPUs, though possibly with additional alignment requirements to ensure atomicity.

Code written to use processor-specific fences can readily be changed to use C++0x fences, provided the operations used to check synchronization (rather than those used to access the synchronized data) are atomic. Existing code may well rely on the atomicity of plain loads and stores on a given CPU, but conversion to C++0x will require using atomic operations for those checks in order to provide the ordering guarantees.

Comment: What part of the standard clarifies that the ordering is however on *all data* and not just the atomics. That's what I'm looking for?  The requirement that you have to use an atomic (as you indicate) would mean these are not proper fences.

Comment: The relevant sections of the standard are 1.10, 29.3 and 29.8. The ordering rules are complicated, but if A is *sequenced-before* B on the same thread, and B *synchronizes-with* C on another thread, and C is *sequenced-before* D on that second thread, then A *happens-before* D, and A and D can access the same data even if they are non-atomic operations. The given paragraphs specify what B and C must be to provide this guarantee. If there is no *happens-before* relationship between non-atomic accesses then you have a data race.

Comment: That seems wrong then (the standard, not your explanation). Hardware fences do not require an atomic operation to create the *happens-before* relationship, the fence alone should be enough.

Comment: See my clarification: existing hardware fences generally **do** require an atomic operation to to create the *happens-before* relationship, it just happens that plain loads and stores of register-sized suitably-aligned data *are* atomic on modern CPUs.

Comment: Since relevant, section 1.9-13 defines what sequenced-before means.

Comment: If you post a small sample of code that you want to convert to C++0x atomics and fences, I'll do the conversion for you.

Comment: Your clarification is helpful.  Section 29.3-2 defines the *synchronizes with* relationship, a piece of the puzzle from section 10.  But it says *a release operation on an atomic object M*.  What would a *release operation* be for fundamentals which are atomic? Would a simple store of an `int` followed by a release-fence qualify as that *release operation*?

Comment: I added a small code example. Would `a` have to be an `atomic<int>` or is its nature as an atomic fundamental sufficient for C++0x?

Comment: With regard to the code example, `a` would have to be `atomic<something>` for the example to work in C++0x. In which case, you would need to use the `load` and `store` member functions to specify `memory_order_relaxed`, as per the example in my answer, otherwise the default `memory_order_seq_cst` ordering will make the fences redundant.

Comment: A "release operation" can only be an atomic operation. You can get *synchronizes-with* relationships using fences, as per 29.8p2-4, but a release fence must be followed by an atomic operation.

Comment: A plain `int` is **never** atomic as far as the C++0x standard is concerned. If you want atomic operations in C++0x, you must use `std::atomic<T>`. It may be that operations on plain `int` are atomic on a given platform, but that's an extension. For example, `i++` is not atomic for plain `int`s on x86, even though it's a single instruction.

Comment: If this is all a  correct interpretation, and I presume it is, then fences are *not* hardware fences and are actually broken. They may differ in size from the underlying type (so says 29.5-9), thus are not a proper replacement.

Comment: On a platform where loads and stores of an aligned `int` are atomic (e.g. x86 linux), `std::atomic<int>` will most likely have the same size and alignment as `int`. It certainly does in my implementation. On platforms where loads and stores of `int` are not atomic, `std::atomic<int>` will do whatever is necessary to guarantee the atomicity of accesses (even if that's to use a mutex). Likewise, `std::thread_fence()` will result in whatever instructions are necessary to provide the appropriate ordering guarantees --- most likely a hw fence instruction (or even a nop, e.g. x86 acquire fence)

Comment: Note that C++0x is designed to be portable. Some platforms don't have atomic `int`-sized objects at all.

Comment: I understand it should be portable, but there is no reason a fence couldn't work without an associated atomic. So long as you have a store/load fence pair, you should be fine. Is there any architecture which has fences where this would not be true?

Comment: Your code example relies on stores to and loads from `a` being atomic. Have you an example where this isn't the case?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y What do you mean by "work"? How could you use such a fence w/o a type guaranteed to support atomic loads and stores?

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Which CPU can't atomically write an `int`? Is such CPU capable of supporting even at least basic C++ code?

Comment: @curiousguy I can't remember the specific CPU, but when we standardized atomics for C++11 there was one CPU model that we wanted to support that only had the atomic operations supported by C++11 `std::atomic_flag`: `test_and_set` and `clear`. Anything else was non-atomic.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams I hope that the C++ committee is not doing the "we can't say that signed integers are 2 compl because some computer somewhere uses sign-mantissa and somehow we need to support it to the detriment of the support for every other system (that actually has a C++ compiler)" dance again.

Comment: @curiousguy For C++11, there was a real platform that supported it with those restrictions. For C++20, `atomic_flag` is getting more operations, and we have added  `std::atomic_signed_lock_free` and `std::atomic_unsigned_lock_free` as required (except for freestanding implementations) lock-free integral types.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams What was that platform and did it had a functional C++ implementation at the time?

Comment: @curiousguy I can't remember the platform, but yes, it had a C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that they are proper fences. The circumstantial evidence being that, after all, they are meant to map to features found in actual hardware and which allows efficient implementation of synchronization algorithms. As you say, fences that apply only to some specific values are 1. useless and 2. not found on current hardware.

That being said, AFAICS the section you quote describes the "synchronizes-with" relationship between fences and atomic operations. For a definition of what this means, see section 1.10 *Multi-threaded executions and data races*. Again, AFAICS, this does not imply that the fences apply only to the atomic objects, but rather I suspect the meaning is that while ordinary loads and stores may pass acquire and release fences in the usual way (one direction only), atomic loads/stores may not.

Wrt. atomic objects, my understanding is that on all targets Linux supports, properly aligned plain integer variables whose sizeof() <= sizeof(*void) are atomic, hence Linux uses normal integers as synchronization variables (that is, the Linux kernel atomic operations operate on normal integer variables). C++ does not want to impose such a limitation, hence the separate atomic integer types. Also, in C++ operations on atomic integer types imply barriers, whereas in the Linux kernel all barriers are explicit (which is sort of obvious since without compiler support for atomic types that is what one must do).

Comment: I've reread section 1.10 and it is entirely unclear to me whether the ordering guarantees apply to non-atomic values. Almost all points indicate `atomic objects` only.  Point 13 mentions non-scalars, and the preceding items relate to relationships, but I'm not positive this truly says the fences work as hardware fences.

Comment: At the assembly level, a load or store on a normal `int` variable is atomic on all CPU supported by linux (such object is always aligned according to the ABI). But at the higher level C/C++ level, a data race has UB. The compiler does not expect normal variables to be changed by another execution (other thread or async signal handler). (Only volatile objects are expected to be modified by ways not visible in the source code.) A compiler can assume that an object retains its previous value if no visible code can alter it in a function.