# C++0X memory_order without fences, applications, chips that support

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-fences

As a followup from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547212/fences-in-c0x-guarantees-just-on-atomics-or-memory-in-general), the `atomic<T>` class specifies most operations with a `memory_order` parameter. In contrast to a fence this memory order affects only the atomic on which it operates. Presumably by using several such atomics you can build a concurrent algorithm where the ordering of other memory is unimportant.

So I have two questions:

1. Can somebody point me to an example of an algorithm/situation that would benefit from the ordering of individual atomic variables and *not* require fences?
2. Which modern processors support this type of behavior? That is, where the compiler won't just translate the specific order into a normal fence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory ordering parameter on operations on `std::atomic<T>` variables does **not** affect the ordering of that operation per se, it affects the ordering relationships that operation creates with other operations.

e.g. `a.store(std::memory_order_release)` on its own tells you nothing about how operations on `a` are ordered with respect to anything else, but paired with a call to `a.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` from another thread, this then order **other** operations --- all writes to **other variables** (including non-atomic ones) done by the thread that did the store to `a` are visible to the thread that did the load, if that load reads the value stored.

On modern processors, some memory orderings on operations are no-ops. e.g. on x86, `memory_order_acquire`, `memory_order_consume` and `memory_order_release` are implicit in the load and store instructions, and do not require separate fences. In these cases the orderings just affect the instruction reordering the compiler can do.

Clarification: The implicit fences in the instructions can mean that the compiler does not need to issue **any** explicit fence instructions if all the memory ordering constraints are attached to individual operations on atomic variables. If you use `memory_order_relaxed` for everything, and add explicit fences then the compiler may well have to explicitly issue those fences as instructions.

e.g. on x86, the `XCHG` instruction carries with it an implicit `memory_order_seq_cst` fence. There is thus no difference between the generated code for the two exchange operations below on x86 --- they both map to a single `XCHG` instruction:

```
std::atomic<int> ai;
ai.exchange(3,std::memory_order_relaxed);
ai.exchange(3,std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

However, I'm not yet aware of any compiler that get rid of the explicit fence instructions in the following code:

```
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
ai.exchange(3,std::memory_order_relaxed);
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

I expect compilers will handle that optimization eventually, but there are other similar cases where the implicit fences will allow better optimization.

Also, `std::memory_order_consume` can **only** be applied to direct operations on variables.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, that's what I meant with *this memory order affects only the atomic on which it operates*.  Both questions still stand.

Comment: If the *syncrhonizes with* relationship is guaranteed simply by specifying the memory order on an `atomic<T>`, and a fence is only guaranteed to work with an `atomic<T>` operation, then why are there even fences in the standard.  Simply using the memory order on the variables would preclude the need for any fence. And since you aren't allowed to use a fence without the atomic, I can't see a situation where you'd actually want a fence.

Comment: A conditional fence is one situation where you'd want to use an explicit fence. e.g. 

    `std::atomic<MyClass*> p;
    if(p.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        std::thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        do_something_with(*p);
    }`

or after a spin-wait loop:

   `while(!p.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
    std::thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);`